# JPA map two entities different entities to one table

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I don't know how to make it clear, and i couldn't think of any good title for this.

Basically, i have a database table which looks like this

| ID | name | another_column | ref_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | asdasd | same_ref1 |
| 2 | name2 | zzzzzz | same_ref1 |
| 3 | name3 | aadas | same_ref2 |
| 4 | name4 | ppppp | same_ref2 |

I have an entity which maps to this table, lets say, and i can use JpaRepository methods :

```
public class TestObject {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String anotherColumn;
   private String refId;
}
```

Is it possible for me to have another object, lets say ParentObject that is mapped based on ref_id column

```
public class ParentObject {
  private String refId;
  private List<TestObject> child;
}
```

That way when I use a `JpaRepository<ParentObject>` for example

```
parentRepository.findById("same_ref2");
```

it returns a ParentObject with two children (lines 3 and 4).

Don't know if I made that clear.

Comment: Do you want a projection for query result mapping?

Comment: Mmm can’t you make directly a query on TestObject on refId that return a List<TestObject>? Why do you need ParentObject?

Comment: What if you use a findByRefId and then a groupingBy with the stream collectors ?

Comment: Well, let's say TestObject is the basic object that lives for sometimes. Once n TestObjects are associated with the REF_ID column, they are not really used anymore. The ParentObject becomes the one used. And ParentObject should be queryable via classic JpaRepository. In my example case, a parentRepository.findAll() should return a list of two ParentObjects.